# How is memory copied to GPU?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, cuda

In parallel programming, specifically for CUDA, is copying memory from the host <-> device done serially or in parallel ?

Comment: In my experience using GPGPU for O(n) algorithm is a waste of effort.

Comment: The answer is yes, for certain algorithms it would. The question is however too broad for the answer to be meaningful.

Comment: Whether the algorithm is O(n) or something else is not really the key criteria, in my view. For example sharpening or blurring an image is definitely directly proportional in time to the number of pixels [with other parameters also affecting the time per pixel, but double number of pixels -> double the time], and perfectly good thing to use the GPU for... A binary tree search, is probably a bad choice - it's not an O(n) algorithm... A bubble sort is equally a bad choice - O(n^2). So the time complexity of the algorithm is really not a good measure for what is a good/bad algorithm.

Comment: Is this question an indirect way of expressing an opinion or a query for a memo on the hybrid computing architectures with bandwidth and latency insights ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "best" things for GPGPU operations are those that can be done massively in parallel (no data dependency from the previous step), and ideally where the GPU has to pass over the same data a few times (blurring an image, for example).

The worst ones are very small, simple, single operations on single data items.

Doing a vector addition (adding two vectors together, which is single pass operation) can be done faster on the GPU, if the data is accessible to the GPU in an easy manner. The GPU I work with in my daily work uses the same memory as the CPU, so it's relatively low cost to transfer the data across. However, if there is large overhead for transferring data, then that may remove any benefit from doing the math on the GPU.

Exactly how the data is copied (if at all) is a system architecture decision, and there are many different variants on that, from narrow to very wide buses, and of course, like I mentioned above, systems where data is shared in the same physical memory, so no copy at all required.

As with just about ANY performance question, the answer is to try different solutions, and see which one is better. For different system architectures, the answer will be different.

Of course, there's also the question of: if we let the GPU do X, can we do something else useful on the CPU - if the CPU is busy with doing X, it obviously can't perform task Y at the same time [unless there are unused cores].

Answer (score 1):

I am only familiar with CUDA, don't know about non-NVIDIA architectures.

1. Yes, for a discrete GPU memory buffers are sent over the PCI and are bound by PCI throughput among other things. Note that this operation does not always require CPU involvement and there are certain hardware capabilities that speed this up.
2. Some GPUs can share the RAM with CPU. In this case "zero copy" is performed - memory pages are simply mapped to GPU. I expect this is how current consoles work (they have AMD chipsets).
3. You can overlap memory transfer and computation. E.g., for really big vector addition, you may split your vectors into partitions - then you may copy subsequent partitions while the computations happen.
4. I believe, it was CUDA6 when we introduced a notion of "unified memory" - it's when you declare a region of memory as available to both CPU and GPU. Then the driver would transfer the data as needed. It was mostly a convenience feature (I would expect the performance would actually degrade for memory-bound loads, like vector addition) but it might be beneficial for tasks when not all data is needed on the device at all times.

Some times you may want to offload tasks to GPU simply so the CPU is available for other loads.